# How to calculate the position assigned to the md-grid-tile of grid list

Tags: css, angular-material

I  am using a full page scroll and have a fixed element on all of the pages it should take the position of an empty grid tile once scrolled to the page.

[image: visual description of what i need]

The position of a grid tile seems to be calculated with this formula

calc((100/num_cols% - **uncnown** px)+1)*num_col-1)

I don't understand what is the unknown part of this equation is, but for example in this 3-cols layout it emits 0.66667 which is equal to 2 divided by 3 (num_cols).

Does anyone know an easier way to do so, or what the unknown part of equation means?

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you have to calculate the offset of the 3rd div from the left. Check the below snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  $('.left-value').text($('.row .col:nth-child(3)').offset().left);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  ;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {}

.col {
  height: 60px;
  width: 31.33333%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<br>
<button>Calculate</button><br> margin form left od 3rd div: <span class="left-value"></span>
```